# android-logging-log4j configuration issue - How to configure more than one file as logs recipients?

Tags: android, log4j

I log in the internal directories but also on the external (removable) sd card if there is one.

I configure the log4j twice and only one might be taken into account.

```
    Tools.configureLog4J(extLoggerpath);
    if (Params.tagFgDebug && fgDebugLocal){Log.i(Params.tagGen, " extLoggerpath = " + extLoggerpath);};
    externalLogger = Logger.getLogger(Baseline.class);

    Tools.configureLog4J(loggerPath);
    if (Params.tagFgDebug && fgDebugLocal){Log.i(Params.tagGen, " loggerPath = " + loggerPath);};
    internalLogger = Logger.getLogger(Baseline.class);
```

Both works, but not together, so my configuration is the cause. What I am doing wrong and how should I configure for 2 files ?

```
public static void configureLog4J(String logDirectory){

    LogConfigurator logConfigurator = new LogConfigurator();
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(logDirectory + File.separator);
    stringBuilder.append(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()));
    stringBuilder.append("android_log.txt");
    logConfigurator.setFileName(stringBuilder.toString());
    logConfigurator.setRootLevel(Level.DEBUG);
    // Set log level of a specific logger

    logConfigurator.setLevel("org.apache", Level.ALL);
    logConfigurator.setUseFileAppender(true);

    logConfigurator.setMaxFileSize(1024 * 1024 * 5);
    logConfigurator.setImmediateFlush(true);
    logConfigurator.configure();

}
```

EDIT : I run more tests. If I switch the order of the configuration calls, it has a consequence : it is always the last one to be configured that will actually work. So how to set 2 files for android-logging-log4j ?

(Confront with this issue, I scrapped both libraries, android-logging-log4j and log4j, and I simply write in file. But I am still interested in the issue)